# IntelliJ and Gradlew: Making ShadowJar the default build target

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build-system

I would like to make ShadowJar the default build target in the gradle file shown below. As things stand right now running the following command attempts to build :bootJar:

```
  gradlew.bat build
```

Is it possible to make this command build shadowJar instead (same thing for IntelliJ)? Here's my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.7'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.foo.bar'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    // tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

//jar { enabled = true } //dont use this   use shadow/shadowJar task instead

test {
}
```

Comment: What is the question? This is a gradle file? So ? And what do you expect us todo?

Comment: I will elaborate more. Thanks for pointing this out.